# Windows Source-Specific-Multicast packets dropped at application layer?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, vlc, multicast, igmp

Both Switch A and Switch B support `IGMPv3`, and device A and device B multicasting a video stream to the same address and port(e.g. 232.0.0.1:12000). vlc/ffplay on Windows 7/10 plays with packets lost, but on Linux, plays smoothly.

I have tested the following scenario:

1. with IGMP v2, both devices multicasting streams(to different addresses), both on Windows and Linux, play smoothly;
2. with IGMP v3, both devices multicasting streams, Linux plays smoothly, Windows 7/10 plays flicked, and Wireshark on Windows shows that no packet is lost;
3. with IGMP v3, only one device multicasting, both Windows and Linux play smoothly.

```
+----------+                                          +--------------+
| Device A |                                          | Windows 7/10 |
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+      +--------------+
      \---------> |          |      |          |----------/
                  | Switch A | ---> | Switch B |
      /---------> |          |      |          |----------\
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+        +-------+
| Device B |                                            | Linux |
+----------+                                            +-------+
```